# SPSS Missing values for skipped questions

Tags: spss, qualtrics

I have done a survey with qualtrics that used skip logic. So question B and C where skipped for everyone who picked C for question A.

Now my data in SPSS for these skipped questions have missing value's (of course) I added missing value labels to the ones that where displayed the question and did not or only partially answered the question. So far so good. But everyone who did not get the question displayed is also a missing value `'.'`. So if I do a frequency table and 250 persons where displayed the question and answered including the ones that I labeled missing. But the table keeps including everyone who filled in the survey, even if they did not get the questions displayed due to skip logic.

So as an example;
Question A is answered by 400 people, 250 picked C and where able to continue with question B and C. While the other 150 skipped question B and C.

How can I label the 150 people who skipped question B and C on purpose, while also define missing value for the people who where able to fill in question B and C but did not or did partially. In the frequency table I only want the amount of people who where able to fill in these specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single frequency table you can use:

```
temp.
select if questionA<>"C".
frequencies questionB questionC.
```

If you want to run some more analyses, you can use `filter`:

```
compute f=(questionA<>"C").
filter by f.
frequencies questionB.
means questionC.
*other analyses.
filter off.
```

If you want to completely get rid of the rows where questions B and C were skipped, you can run:

```
select if questionA<>"C".
```

Please note, though, this will delete those rows from your dataset. If you save the data after running `select`, there's no going back. So use it carefully and keep a backup of your data first.

Comment: So in my case 1 question is; Where do you buy your groceries? With 6 multiple choice options. All the answers selected lead to 10 additional factors of "why do you shop there" with a likert scale of 5. 428 People answered, so if only 30 people answered to question 1; "discount supermarket' it leaves at least 392 missing values which are not really missing. Is the option you gave the fastest way do deal with this? And does this solution also work with doing crosstabs for instance?

Comment: sounds like your best choice is to work with filters. You filter out anyone who doesn't shop in "discount supermarket", run whatever analyses you need, including crosstabs, then run `filter off`. Then you can filter out anyone who doesn't buy in "local grocery" and run your analyses again etc'

Comment: Just found this code: do repeat var=q2 to q10.
if (q1 = 0 and missing(var)) var = 9999.
end repeat.
execute.  Can I adjust this to make the missing values which are supposed to be missed 9999 and the once who where not supposed to be missed 99?

Comment: sure you can but they'll still show up in your analysis if you don't filter them out

Comment: Oke, filtered the real missing values by the use of filters and then used filters to generate frequency tabels. Easy to use and it's just what I needed. Thank you very much. Just one more question for now:) I want to make age groups and see if this was of influence in their answers. So is age a factor in their choice of where they buy groceries. Do I also have to use the filters to generate a crosstab with chi-square?

Comment: the filter just determines which rows will enter the analysis - whatever the statistics you are adding to it. If you want all the rows in this specific analysis - turn the filter off.